# After a sleep on Windows 11, Docker Desktop containers disappear

Tags: docker-desktop, windows-11

I am using Docker Desktop on Windows 11 to start and stop containers. When I close Docker Desktop and the computer goes to sleep, whenever I come back and relaunch Docker Desktop, the containers are gone. If I then restart the computer, they reappear. I have observed this consistently. Why are the containers lost after a sleep ?
If I don't close the Docker Desktop application, then after a sleep the containers remain there. I also have a hard time restarting Docker Desktop from the mouse menu. It just hangs there displaying : "Docker Desktop stopping..."

[image]

Comment: Me too. It is unbearable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple way to bring back the containers. In a windows power shell or terminal, I do

```
docker ps -a
```

Then when I reopen Docker Desktop, the containers are back !